# What does .! (dot exclamation mark) mean in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, syntax

I wrote the following program:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

temp = None
def changeColor(event, e):
    # print('Positional arumgent passed:', x)
    print('event: ', event.widget)
    e2 = event.widget
    if e2['bg'] == 'white':
        e2['bg'] = 'black'
    elif e2['bg'] == 'black':
        e2['bg'] = 'white'
    global temp
    temp = event

entries = [[None for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)]

for y in range(3):
    for x in range(3):
        e = Entry(root, width=3, bg='white', bd=0, borderwidth=3)
        e.bind('<Double-Button-1>', lambda x: changeColor(x, e))
        e.grid(column=x, row=y)
        entries[y][x] = e

root.mainloop()
```

which, in the terminal, produced the output,

```
event:  .!entry5
event:  .!entry6
event:  .!entry8
...
```

When I examined the one of the event.widgets (stored in temp) in the terminal, I got,

```
>>> temp.widget
<tkinter.Entry object .!entry8>
>>> print(temp.widget)
.!entry8
```

I've never seen this syntax before and I was unable to find anything in the docs or here on stackoverflow about it.

Does anyone know what it is? Could you kindly explain/describe?

Comment: The fact that it isn't python code doesn't mean that it doesn't mean something. If they weren't meant to communicate something they wouldn't be included in the __str__.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.!` is not a general Python thing, it's just how the tkinter library names widgets that are not otherwise given a name. `entry` comes [from here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f89d7bcdeed22382aa2af5e3b3e1c68d21004bcb/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L2536), since this widget is an `Entry` class. The exclamation point & number suffix are assigned [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f89d7bcdeed22382aa2af5e3b3e1c68d21004bcb/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L2539-L2544), presumably being given a `!` so that auto-generated, class-name-derived widget names don't overlap with those assigned by the user. And the leading period is how widgets are named when they don't have a named parent; if they did, it would be [`<parentname>.<childname>`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f89d7bcdeed22382aa2af5e3b3e1c68d21004bcb/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L2546-L2549).

Comment: small correction: all widget names have a leading period, even those that have a named parent. The first dot represents the root window, much like "/" represents the root folder of a filesystem.